# Error installing hwcounter using "pip install hwcounter"

Tags: python, pip, package, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I am getting the following error when I try to install hwcounter using pip :

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for hwcounter
  Running setup.py clean for hwcounter
Failed to build hwcounter
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hwcounter, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have searched and tried for some solutions like :

- `pip install cmake`
- `pip install wheel` (wheel(0.42.0) is already installed on my device)
- tried updating pip

Here is a screenshot of the complete error message :
[image]

P.S : I am facing this issue on my windows 11 laptop as well as Raspberry PI3. I have a dual boot ubuntu (22.04.3) OS too and this command worked perfectly fine on it.

Answer (score 0):

From [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/paulsmith/hwcounter/issues/2#:%7E:text=Hello%2C%0AI%20faced%20the%20same%20problem%20when%20trying%20to%20install%20hwcounter%20package%20on%20windows%2010.%0ALater%2C%20this%20package%20was%20successfully%20installed%20on%20Ubuntu%2020.0.), installing this package on Ubuntu seems to work fine just as you noted. The OP [here had issues installing on Windows](https://github.com/paulsmith/hwcounter/issues/2).

One thing you might do is to keep using Ubuntu for this package or you might want to read the suggested fixes in that thread. Do note that this package hasn't been maintained since 2018 and there's no official information on the supported OS.

Finally, ensure you are using a supported python version as [hwcounter supports Python 3.4 - 3.6](https://pypi.org/project/hwcounter/#description:%7E:text=Programming%20Language).